# return RedirectToRouteResult in Non Controller class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception, .net-core

I have a .Net Core app which accesses a seperate Api, when I get an Api unauthorised error I'd like to redirect the user back to Authorisation

So in my repository layer I have this method call

```
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    exceptionMiddleware.ErrorResponse(response.StatusCode, bodyContent.ToString());
}
```

And I'd like to use RedirectToRouteResult like so

```
public RedirectToRouteResult ErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode statusCode, string bodyContent)
    {
        if (statusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        {
            return new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Index", controller = "Auth" }));
        }
        if (statusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        {
            throw new Exception("Api connection error");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(bodyContent);
        }
    }
```

But when I hit `if(statusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)` the RedirectToRouteResult isn't succeeding & just continues to the next catch block.

How do correctly I redirect from a non controller class

Comment: Just to clarify, your `if` block is looking for a `403 Forbidden` and not a `401 Unauthorized`, which is a separate HTTP code. Is the `if` body being skipped or is the return itself running and not behaving as you expect?

Comment: I'm returning a 403 from the API when the JWT token expires, so that part is woking ok, it enters the if statement but doesn't succeed in RedirectToRouteResult. Is this something that can only be used when inheriting from Controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any form of redirect, including the ones that a `RedirectToRoute` method or `RedirectToRouteResult` result produces, is ultimately just a response (generally a `301 Redirect` or `302 Redirect`) that has to be sent back to the consuming client (in this case likely a browser), and it's up to the client to receive that HTTP code and result and to act on it (or not).

It's not fully clear where you return the result that you're producing in the `ErrorResponse` method, but if the original request was made from a browser to a controller and then down to your inner API layer, you'll have to ensure that the response is somehow surfaced back to the controller to issue back to the browser so it can do its thing.

If you want to share some additional code showing how the UI/MVC layer is interacting with the user and the inner API layer, I can update with some additional context.

**Update** As described in the comments, it sounds like the process as:

Browser <-> Controller <-> Service <-> Repository

If there's something you need the browser to do based on an event in the repository, you need to bubble that back up. It's convenient that your inner API is throwing HTTP codes directly, but that's not necessarily always going to be the case for a data layer, so be weary of tight coupling by having the repository try to presuppose the existence of a controller that knows what to do with HTTP codes and routes; it may be preferable to have the repository just surface that there was an authorization error and let the controller choose to issue the redirect behavior there.

Comment: Throwing an exception and handling it in the presentation layer should be enough. Creating a custom exception and responding with a redirect when it occurs, whether is in a middleware or controller

Comment: Thank you Adam. So the request goes Controller --> Service --> Repository (which makes the API call) --> I get the 403 back because JWT has expired then the Repository method calls ErrorResponse, so the call stack is the Repository class. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: So do I need that to bubble back up to the controller? I was hoping to catch it before then  & just redirect it.

Comment: Added some additional content to the answer

Comment: Thanks Adam, that was really helpful